# Read An Input.md file and output a .html file Haskell

Tags: html, haskell, character, converters

I had a question concerning some basic transformations in Haskell.
Basically, I have a written Input file, named Input.md. This contains some markdown text that is read in my project file, and I want to write a few functions to do transformations on the text. After completing these functions under a function called convertToHTML, I have output the file as an .html file in the correct format.

```
module Main
(
convertToHTML,
main
) where

import System.Environment (getArgs)
import System.IO
import Data.Char (toLower, toUpper) 

process :: String -> String 
process s = head $ lines s


convertToHTML :: String -> String
convertToHTML str = do
     x <- str
     if (x == '#')
     then "<h1>"
     else return x
      --convertToHTML x = map toUpper x

main = do

    args <- getArgs                     -- command line args

    let (infile,outfile) = (\(x:y:ys)->(x,y)) args

    putStrLn $ "Input file:  " ++ infile
    putStrLn $ "Output file: " ++ outfile

    contents <- readFile infile

    writeFile outfile $ convertToHTML contents
```

So,

1. How would I read through my input file, and transform any line that starts with a # to an html tag
2. How would I read through my input file once more and transform any WORD that is surrounded by `_word_` (1 underscore) to another html tag
3. Replace any Character with an html string.

I tried using such functions such as Map, Filter, ZipWith, but could not figure out how to iterate through the text and transform each text. Please if anybody has any suggestions. I've been working on this for 2 days straight and have a bunch of failed code to show for a couple of weeks and have a bunch of failed code to show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried using such functions such as Map, Filter, ZipWith, but could not figure out how to iterate through the text and transform each text.

Because they work on appropriate element collection. And they don't really "iterate"; you simply have to feed the appropriate data. Let's tackle the `#` problem as an example.

Our file is one giant `String`, and what we'd like is to have it nicely split in lines, so `[String]`. What could do it for us? I have no idea, so let's just [search Hoogle for `String -> [String]`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=String+-%3E+%5BString%5D).

Ah, there we go, [`lines`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:lines) function! Its counterpart, `unlines`, is also going to be useful. Now we can write our line wrapper:

```
convertHeader :: String -> String
convertHeader [] = [] -- that prevents us from calling head on an empty line
convertHeader x  = if head x == '#' then "<h1>" ++ x ++ "</h1>"
                                    else x
```

and so:

```
convertHeaders :: String -> String
convertHeaders = unlines . map convertHeader . lines
--              ^String   ^[String]         ^[String] ^String
```

As you can see the function first converts the file to lines, maps `convertHeader` on each line, and the puts the file back together.

[<kbd>**See it live on Ideone**</kbd>](http://ideone.com/GXqQ3r)

Try now doing the same with `words` to replace your formatting patterns. As a bonus exercise, change `convertHeader` to count the number of `#` in front of the line and output `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>` and so on accordingly.

Comment: not sure how to direct a response to yours yet. haha, but I posted a response below.

Comment: Hey, I was wondering if you could get me started on the word conversion using words and unwords. I've been going through some trial and error code, but I just dont know where to use the functions within my code. I've tried duplicating convertHeader and convertHeaders format, and also tried guards. But nothing has been working out for me